# Deploying to a Tomcat server which is already running outside of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have installed Tomcat server on my PC and I have added it as a `service` in Windows. So now it starts each time I boot my computer. Now, in IntelliJ I have configured an application server, and that is my Tomcat server, however when trying to "run" the application it says that the port is already in use....and it is ofcourse since Tomcat is started on boot. Is it possible that IntelliJ deploys to the already running Tomcat server instead of trying to start again?

Comment: In Intellij you can configure deployment actions. Open tomcat configuration of your IDE and you see: Perform on 'Update' action: Choose redeploy and that should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to deploy to Tomcat started outside of IDEA, use the [Tomcat Remote](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html) Run/Debug configuration type.

The difference of the **Remote** configuration is that it doesn't start the server, ensure you create **Remote** configuration, not Local:

[image: Tomcat Remote]

It's possible to update application without restarting the server, refer to the [Updating Applications on Application Servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html) help section.

Comment: I have changed to "Redeploy" when I press "run" but I am still getting an error stating that the server is already in use on that port?

Comment: See this link: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html#configuration. But it tells how to update existing application in running tomcat. I can not find any informantion how to deploy new application in running tomcat.

Comment: When creating Tomcat configuration there is a choice: Local and Remote, create **Remote** configuration instead of Local, it will not start Tomcat.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - could you help me out with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261515/how-to-configure-intellij-11-remote-tomcat-6-maven-imported-modules, please?

Comment: Where on earth does it deploy it to? I'm also using IntelliJ (12) and it indicates the app has deployed, but I can't find it. It's not listed in the apps in ./manager in Tomcat (7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Jrebel** plugin. It will be helpful to update your application without restarting your server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you add some further insight on how to use it, or give a link?

Comment: Sure Ian H,
If you are working with eclipse you can get more info by using the following link
https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/eclipse/