# JSF folder deployment to Tomcat

Tags: jsf, tomcat, deployment, jsf-2, tomcat7

*RackSpace Cloud Server Ubuntu-12.04, JSF-2.0, Mojarra-2.1.17, Intellij Idea-11.1.2, Windows-8, Tomcat 7.0.26, JDK-6.*

As it can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085371/tomcat-intellij-idea-remote-deploy) I am trying to deploy my project to the remote Tomcat server. Because of the Intellij Idea's remote server deploy feature is not working correctly, I am trying to do it manually.

I had placed the the `exploded war archive` folder(artifact) into `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` on the server and renamed folder as ROOT. It seems like; `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT`

After restarting Tomcat from command line on the server, site can be reached by  *IPAddress:8080* correctly. And startup page seems good, even it loads it's CSS correctly. But after trying to login, it's not working like on the local. The problem can not be about implementation because it works perfect on the local machine.

Stack trace after trying to login:

```
javax.faces.FacesException
helpers.JSFHelper.getManagedBean(JSFHelper.java:27)
servlet.facebook.FacebookCallBackServlet.doPost(FacebookCallBackServlet.java:202)
servlet.facebook.FacebookCallBackServlet.doGet(FacebookCallBackServlet.java:48)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
```

Here is JSFHelper's getManagedBean:

```
public static Object getManagedBean(final String beanName) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Object bean;

        try {
            ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
            bean = elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, beanName);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new FacesException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        if (bean == null) {
            throw new FacesException("Managed bean with name '" + beanName
                    + "' was not found. Check your faces-config.xml or @ManagedBean annotation.");
        }

        return bean;
    }
```

Comment: You're only showing the `FacesException` which you wrapped yourself. Please show the actual runtime exception causing this problem.

Comment: @BalusC Actually I can't see the exact run time exception could you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085371/tomcat-intellij-idea-remote-deploy

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Are you sure that you're running the code as shown here? Do `e.printStackTrace()` before you rethrow it. As to the other question, sorry IntelliJ+Ubuntu is beyond me. My first guess would be just a firewall issue.

Comment: @BalusC it says sth like that on the Tomcat 7 log file `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet.facebook.FacebookCallBackServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
javax.faces.FacesException` Me and my developer friend is very disappointed and demotivated right now. We are frustrating with remote deployment for 3 days. Is there any other combination instead of ubuntu+intellij to deploy a JSF-2 web site? Or a more suitable hosting service instead Rackspace cloud? We need a solution to debug and being in the continious development.

Comment: As long as you don't know what the caught `RuntimeException` is, we can't help you further. Simple as that. Debug/log it.