# How to enable the Perform on 'Update' action option in the remote Tomcat run configuration in IntelliJ?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

Given:

- IntelliJ 11
- A project with Web and Spring facets.
- A remote Tomcat run configuration

There should be the **Perform on 'Update' action** option on the run configuration dialog, but there is none! How do I make it appear?

Here is my remote tomcat run configuration dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "on update" configuration depends on the artifact type your are deploying on the server and if the server is local or remote.

Check that you first selected the artifact to deploy, then the on update configuration should become visible.

From jetbrains [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html):

> In the run/debug configurations for remote servers, the available
>   application update options are limited to those for packed artifacts.
>   Also, the Restart server option is not available.

HIH

Comment: The passage does not say the option is unavailable. It only says that the choice of on update options is limited. But the option itself is available for both remote and local - the documentation link you give tells it.

Comment: Did you set the artifact you want to deploy (tab deployment)? what is the type of artifact? On my intellij v12, the option appears only after you select the artifact

Comment: Oh, I did  not think about it this way. Let me check.

Comment: You are correct. This UI is bad. One has to jump between the tabs, I never expected that. Could you modify your answer so that I could credit you?