# How to config intellij idea and tomcat 8

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I would like to config intellij idea + tomcat8 as remote server

I installed tomcat8 as windows service, and now its running.

I tried to run the default spring mvc project, and i get this error message:

Error running Tomcat8 (is the server name): unable to connect to the localhost:1099

I didnt find a tutorial, or something how to config intellij idea + tomcat8

Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: Did you try this?

http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12#Integrating_Tomcat_Server_with_IntelliJ_IDEA

Comment: this tutorial create local server, but i already have server. i need remote server :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying to a Tomcat server which is already running outside of IntelliJ IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461717/deploying-to-a-tomcat-server-which-is-already-running-outside-of-intellij-idea)

Comment: it not helped for me...

Comment: can you give the full error log?

Comment: i dont have got error log, i just got a toast message, that Error running tomcat8 remote: unable to connect to the localhost:1099